# how to merge two pandas DataFrames and aggregate one specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 DataFrames:

```
         city  count    school
0    New York      1  school_3
1  Washington      1  School_4
2  Washington      1  School_5
3          LA      1  School_1
4          LA      1  School_4

         city  count    school
0    New York      1  School_3
1  Washington      1  School_1
2          LA      1  School_3
3          LA      2  School_4
```

I want to get the this result:

```
         city  count    school
0    New York      2  school_3
1  Washington      1  School_1
2  Washington      1  School_4
3  Washington      1  School_5
4          LA      1  School_1
5          LA      1  School_3
6          LA      3  School_4
```

Following is the code.

```
d1 = [{'city':'New York', 'school':'school_3', 'count':1},
      {'city':'Washington', 'school':'School_4', 'count':1},
      {'city':'Washington', 'school':'School_5', 'count':1},
      {'city':'LA', 'school':'School_1', 'count':1},
      {'city':'LA', 'school':'School_4', 'count':1}]


d2 = [{'city':'New York', 'school':'School_3', 'count':1},
      {'city':'Washington', 'school':'School_1', 'count':1},
      {'city':'LA', 'school':'School_3', 'count':1},
      {'city':'LA', 'school':'School_4', 'count':2}]

x1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
x2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
#just get empty DataFrame
print pd.merge(x1, x2)
```

How to get the aggregate result ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> pd.concat([x1, x2]).groupby(["city", "school"], as_index=False)["count"].sum()
       city    school        count
0          LA  School_1      1
1          LA  School_3      1
2          LA  School_4      3
3    New York  School_3      1
4    New York  school_3      1
5  Washington  School_1      1
6  Washington  School_4      1
7  Washington  School_5      1
```

Note that New York appears 2 times because of a typo in the data (`school_3` vs `School_3`).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a slightly different implementation from @elyase's solution using `pandas.DataFrame.merge(...)`

```
x1.merge(x2,on=['city', 'school', 'count'], how='outer').groupby(['city', 'school'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()
```

When timed in `ipython notebook %timeit` this method is marginally faster than @elyase's (<1ms)

```
100 loops, best of 3: 6.25 ms per loop  #using concat(...) with @elyase's solution
100 loops, best of 3: 5.49 ms per loop #using merge(...) in this solution
```

Also, if you want to use `pandas aggregate` functionality you can also do:

```
x1.merge(x2,on=['city', 'school', 'count'], how='outer').groupby(['city', 'school'], as_index=False).agg(numpy.sum)
```

The only disclaimer is that using `agg(...)` is the slowest of the 3 solutions.

Obviously all 3 provide the correct result:

```
         city    school  count
0          LA  School_1      1
1          LA  School_3      1
2          LA  School_4      3
3    New York  School_3      1
4    New York  school_3      1
5  Washington  School_1      1
6  Washington  School_4      1
7  Washington  School_5      1
```